# Kernel and Image of an integral.

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Im struggling to answer a question where $F: P_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_{3}(\mathbb{R}) $

$$F(f)(x)=\int^{x+1}_{2-x} (1-t)f(t) dt$$

So to find the Kernel do i set the integral equal to 0 and sub in $f(t)$ as $at^{2}+bt+c$ and integrate sub in my limits. Then as i have a constant term i get the Kernel=1 as a constant times by 0 maps the constant to zero. From this how do i find the basis of this, and the basis of the image.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by finding the images of the standard basis vectors $\{1,x,x^2\}$. From those, you can write down a matrix for $F$, find its kernel and image via row-reduction, and translate that back into polynomials.